# HTML Text Input not allowing text input

Tags: html, css

I having been running into some strange problems with a webpage that I have designed. For some reason, when you click inside the text input box, it doesn't place the pointer inside and doesn't allow you to type inside the text input box. Here is the URL of the page:
http://worldrunningleague.com/iphone/login.php
I've poured over the code on the page and can't, for the life of me, figure out what I'm doing wrong! I've done this a thousand times before and I've not clue why its different this time. Thanks!

--UPDATE--
Just so you know, it works fine in Firefox, but not Chrome or most importantly, mobile Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the below in your CSS.

```
    * {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that! :)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have an internal stylesheet with this in it:

```
* { -webkit-user-select: none; }
```

I don't know exactly what that does, but I would have to guess that it would disallow selecting the input in WebKit browsers (which includes Google Chrome and Mobile Safari). My guess would be to just remove it and see if it works then.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```